# Installing 32 bit apt packages on 64 bit Ubuntu on Arm (Raspberry Pi)

Tags: apt, 64-bit, 32-bit, raspberrypi, arm

After switching from Raspbian OS (32-bit) to Ubuntu 20.04.1 (64-bit) for the Raspberry Pi, I found out one of my favourite packages was missing: usbip.

Although I could likely download the packages manually and install it, I instead want to know how to allow all 32-bit packages to show up in my apt searches and available packages with the 64-bit versions of those packages taking preference if versions for both architectures exist.

Although I'm not entirely sure on this, I imagine it is like x86_64 and x64 in the sense that 32-bit programs are compatible with 64-bit operating systems but not the other way around.

Can I do this? And even if it is theoretically doable, would there be certain 32-bit packages that don't play nicely with 64-bit?

The architecture under `uname -a` is listed as **aarch64** in my current 64-bit Ubuntu installation. Under 32-bit Raspbian it was listed as **ArmV8-A**.

Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried linux-tools? usbip merged into linux-tools and it should be available.

Comment: @Rinzwind I wasn't aware of this so thank you. Does that mean my question is invalid? In the sense that 32 bit packages are available, and that I was just looking for something that no longer exists?

Or is my question still applicable.

Comment: No I would if I was you try if it works. And if it does make it an answer so others can benefit from it. If it does NOT work add it to the question and Ill remove the comments so someone can come up with an answer that does work ;)

Comment: @Rinzwind seeing as nobody responded I'll close this down but thank you for your help Rinzwind :)